# how to create unique constraints in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like create a unique constraint which specifies that for an ID and BriefID there should be a Unique Name.

eg. the following would not be allowed because of the constraint.

```
ID   BriefID   Name
12    32        first
12    32        first
```

the table structure is as follows.

```
 PK ID                   int    
    Name                 nvarchar(50)   
 FK BriefID              int    
    StatusID             int    
    StartDate            datetimeoffset(7)  
    EndDate              datetime   
    FrequencyID          int    
    MaxArticleDisplay    int    
    LastDateAlertSent    datetime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_ID_BriefID UNIQUE(ID, BriefID, Name)
```

With this, you could not insert these two rows you mentioned in your question. Trying to insert the second row would cause a constraint violation and would not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_TABLENAME_001] ON [TABLENAME]
(
    ID,
    BriefID,
    Name
)
```